# How to replace part of string with asterisk in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to replace part of the string with asterisk (* sign).
How can I achieve that? Been searching around but I can't find a solution for it.

For example, I getting 0123456789 from backend, but I want to display it as ******6789 only.

Please advise.
Many thanks.

Comment: keep in mind anyone will be able to see what you sent from the backend, modifying in the frontend will not hide it from the end user.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  String test = "0123456789";
  int numSpace = 6;
  String result = test.replaceRange(0, numSpace, '*' * numSpace);
  print("original: ${test}  replaced: ${result}");
}
```

Notice in dart the [multiply operator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/operator_multiply.html) can be used against string, which basically just creates N version of the string.  So in the example, we are padding the string 6 times with'*'.

Output:

```
original: 0123456789  replaced: ******6789
```

Answer (score 8):

try using replaceRange. It works like magic, no need for regex. its replaces your range of values with a string of your choice.

```
//for example
prefixMomoNum = prefs.getString("0267268224");

prefixMomoNum = prefixMomoNum.replaceRange(3, 6, "****");
//Output 026****8224
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily achieve it with a `RegExp` that matches all characters but the last `n` char.

Example:

```
void main() {
  String number = "123456789";
  String secure = number.replaceAll(RegExp(r'.(?=.{4})'),'*'); // here n=4
  print(secure);
}
```

Output: `*****6789`

Hope that helps!